# Change Image of NSButton

Tags: swift, macos

Im trying to change the background image of my button but it gives me this error :

```
Value of type '(NSButton) -> ()' has no member 'image'

likeButton.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("like"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setBackgroundImage` function to change it.

For example

```
likeButton.setBackgroundImage(anImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
```